# Inserting multiple record into Juction Table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've two tables

```
<jobs> { jobID(p-k) , JobName }
<Account> {SSU(p-k),emploeeName}
```

and 
junction Table to make a relationship between the above tables,

```
<JobLists> { No(p-k) , jobID(f-k) , SSU(f-k) }
```

and I want to insert data to <jobList> table when user click "pick"
in the below code, it works fine if I add one job at a time, but when I choose more than one Job it gives me an error, 
I think because I'm trying to pass more than one jobId in my query, and it fails, 
please how do make this code work, if user pick one or more jobs at a time..
I really appreciate your help

```
if( isset($_POST['pick']) ){
        if( empty($_POST['JobId']) || $_POST['JobId'] == 0 ){
            echo"<h4>   choose something </h4>";
                            }else{


                              echo "what do u want to do..!! ";

include('../CIEcon.php');  //$dbCIE


   $impid = implode("' , '" ,  $_POST['JobId']);
   echo $impid; 
$sqlInsert ="INSERT INTO JobsLists(`JobID` , `SSU`) VALUES(".$impid.",'$SSU' )";
$MyQuery=  mysqli_query($dbCIE, $sqlInsert) or die(mysqli_error($dbCIE));


// TEST ONLY ////////----------------------------------------////////////
if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbCIE) > 0) {
   echo "You have successfully added a job.<br><br>";
}else{"Error occurred when trying to add a job. <br> " ; }
////////----------------------------------------////////////
```

Comment: The number of fields in an INSERT statement is not allowed to change.
You must do a query for each JobID, SSU pair or add more value pairs to the query.

Use an foreach loop for example.

Comment: If you are using implode to make an array into a string, if you have more than one value you will inserting three values in your SQL query while only defining 2 columns

Comment: yeah, should I do a while loop for eacho JobId, to have separate query ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not just loop the Job IDs?

```
foreach($_POST['JobID'] as $impid) {
    $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO JobLists(`JobID` , `SSU`) VALUES(".$impid.",'$SSU' )";
}
```

Comment: thank u but it gave me an error :
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: thanks for the hint, i made it work, based on ur reply.. thanks u